# Multiprocessing python doesn't behave as expected

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hello I am working on running two different functions from `main()` with the multiprocessing library :

```
Coap = multiprocessing.Process(target=runCoapSync(iotComponent))
huis=multiprocessing.Process(target=runHuis(iotComponent))
huis.start()
Coap.start()
```

The problem is that the function `runHuis()` does not get triggered but if I comment lines for running the other function, the function `runHuis()` works as expected. I use the very same structure somewhere else in my code but it's working great.

Here's the code of both functions:

```
def runHuis(iotDevice):
    print("----------------1---------------")
    LCD=iotDevice.connectedHUIs[0]
    while True:
        LCD.alertHuman(iotDevice.connectedSensors[0].data.value)

def runCoapSync(iotDevice):
    print("----------------2---------------")
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(runCoap(iotDevice))
```

Comment: What version of Python is this? Which operating system are you running on?

Comment: I am working on Python3 on a raspberry Pi so the OS is a raspbian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process` requires the [target](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) to be a callable with optional args:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=runCoapSync, args=(iotComponent,))
```

Since you're calling it instead, the remaining program waits for `runCoapSync` to complete.

Comment: Great solution, thank you but don't you find it's weird because when i was passing the arguments myself it worked very well for `runCoapSync()` function.

Comment: @VincentNAHMIAS it was calling the first function, but in the _same_ process, since the call was happening even before the process was instantiated.

Comment: oh okay i have understood, thanks for the explanation !